# First boot Install Windows on SSD using USB flash memory

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, ssd, bios

I'm trying to run my own pc build. I want to install windows from a USB flash to the SSD I installed in the PC. I want to know how to configure that in BIOS setup before and after the installation. I have a Gigabyte GA-Z97-D3H motherboard. To make the question more specific, is it right that i have to boot from the flash containing windows, perform installation, reboot and finally change boot drive to SSD from BIOS? or just install windows and I'm done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it right that i have to boot from the flash containing windows,
>   perform installation, reboot and finally change boot drive to SSD from
>   BIOS?

Yep, that's all you have to do.

Comment: It could be actually much easier. If you first boot from a flash, at the end of the installation windows will ask you to remove it. There will be no flash in the BIOS any more so the SSD will be the boot drive UNLESS you have multiple storage devices then you may want to check again and make sure the one with windows installed is the boot drive. for me the SSD was already the boot drive so i didn't have to change.

Comment: @onlyforthis it's still wise to change the boot order so you don't boot off a USB by mistake :P